# Can anyone help me resolve this testng xml parsing issue?

Tags: xml, parsing, testng.xml

I am using this testng xml, but getting parsing error, can anyone look into it.

Error:

> org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 61; columnNumber: 3; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
>
> at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:327)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)......

My testng xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Client Connect Automated Test Suite" verbose="1">
   <listeners>
      <listener class-name="PitneyBowes.ClientConnectTestAutomation.ReportListener.TestListener" />
   </listeners>
   <test name="Regression Suite">
      <groups>
         <run>
            <include name="regression" />
         </run>
      </groups>
      <classes>
         <class name="PitneyBowes.ClientConnectTestAutomation.CaseListTest" />
         <class name="PitneyBowes.ClientConnectTestAutomation.CaseCreateTest" />
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Since this document doesn't have 61 lines, my suspicion would be that you are looking at the wrong document.

Comment: Try changing the http to https in the DOCTYPE line. I remember facing a SAXParseException because of this.